# How to move to next page in datagridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to move to next page in datagridview.I have n number of pages.I enabled autopaging.Its showing ">" link.But when i am clicking it is not moving to next page.My grid is inside a update panel....What is the reason..Pls help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to take a look at this -> [GridView Examples for ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479347.aspx)

I am asuming you mean GridView - The DataGridView is a control for Windows.Forms